# Como usar los radio button in mvc 5 checked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

como puedo hacer para selecionar un radiobutton y este mande llamar un método, así pero en MVC5 C# web. 
[image: radioButton]

Comment: El codigo en formato **texto** por favor!. Gracias :)

Comment: que no te funciona ahi?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses un GroupRadioButton, si te sirve usarlos, ellos hacen la lógica de cambio de opción y además traen la opción de SelectedValue

por ejemplo:

```
if(groupRadio.SelectedValue == 1)
{
// Aqui tu codigo
}
```